# Facebook Like button: Post on wall without adding comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have added a FB like button to my site. I need to accomplish the following:
Once a user clicks the Like button a comment box appears with the "Post to Facebook" button. I need posts to appear on the wall without the need of adding the comment (preferably removing the comment box also will do)

Current scenario:

- Press Like button
- Add a comment and press "Post to Facebook"
- The post appears at once on the wall

But if I add the post without adding a comment it does not appear on the wall but it appaears on the **Activity log**

Answer (score 1):

Ive been trying to get the same result with no success. My "solution" was to replace the like button by the share button. That way you make sure that the link will always be seen on the user profile/timeline and their friends.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button with a `<div>` and set its "overflow" to "hidden".
So, it should be something like:

```
<div style="width:70px;overflow:hidden;">
    <fb:like href="your_link" send="false" layout="button_count" width="65" show_faces="false" action="like" />
</div>
```

Not the most beautiful way, but it works...